# What is the difference between Hamburger icon and Ellipsis icon?

Tags: navigation, icons, floating-action-button

I'm working on an enterprise application with a possible responsive design in future. What is the difference between the hamburger icon (3 horizontal bars) and the Ellipsis (3 horizontal / vertical dots)? Can a screen have both the icons together - once being primary navigation and the other being a secondary actions button (could be additional information or actions etc)?

Any insights would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The hamburger is usually to open a global-navigation menu, in material design they call this a [navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18T1S.png).

The ellipsis are an icon to signify additional controls (more) available for this specific page / context.

[image]

All screens can indeed have both icons together. Dropbox for instance uses the ellipsis in the tables to signify additional controls:

[image]

The ellipsis are called dropdown menues in material design: https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#dropdown-menu

In iOS it is generally referred to as the more menu:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarsystemitem/more